# How to programmatically add a PSCmdlet to a Powershell pipeline?

Tags: c#, powershell, sdk, pipeline

I'd like to programmatically assemble and run a **pipeline containing my own PSCmdlet**.
However, the Pipeline class only allows to add strings and Commands (which are constructed from strings in turn).

```
var runspace = ...;
var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.AddCommand("Get-Date"); // ok
var myCmdlet = new MyCmdlet();
pipeline.AddCommand(myCmdlet); // Doesn't compile - am I fundamentally 
       // misunderstanding some difference between commands and commandlets?
foreach(var res in pipeline.Invoke()) {...}
```

I believe that what I'm doing should basically make sense... or is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your cmdlet should have a well-defined syntax, based on what you put in the Cmdlet attribute.

For instance, here's the start of where I create my own clear-host cmdlet to replace the built-in clear-host function:

```
<Cmdlet("clear", "host")> _
 Public Class Clearhost
     Inherits Cmdlet
```

From the Cmdlet attribute, the syntax for my cmdlet is "clear-host".  You should be able to use that (since it's a string) and add it to the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

After searching through other answers and poking around `System.Management.Automation` in ILSpy, I'm convinced that it is impossible to add `Cmdlet` instances directly. PowerShell requires you to use strings, which is unfortunate if you just want to drive it from .NET using proper types.